# How to search the given string inside a string WITHOUT javascript methods?

Tags: javascript

As i'm trying to search a given string inside a string using for loop.
Here i don't want to use any java-script method like split,regx,indexOf or any ES6 methods.

This is what i have used but i didn't achieved . Can please suggest for below code.

```
var str = 'Hello Hello word world going Hello world';
var strToSearch = "Hello"; //search this in str

var strMatch = "";

function wordMatch(str, length) {
  for (var h = length; h < str.length; h++) {
    if (str[h] === ' ') {
      console.log('white Space')
    } else {
      strMatch += str[h];
      //
      if (strMatch === strToSearch) {

          var len2 = str.length - strMatch.length;
          console.log(len2,"Matched...");
          wordMatch(str, len2);

          //return false;
      }else{
        console.log('cont.........................')

      }
    }

  }
}
wordMatch(str, 0);
```

Thank you

Comment: You "want" to not use them? Or that's the assignment? And why ignore whitespace? What if the string being searched has whitespace?

Comment: Yes i don't want to use them. For my reference i have used to check the white-space nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Small Changes :

```
var str = 'Hello Hello word world going Hello world';
var strToSearch = "Hello"; //search this in str

var strMatch = "";

function wordMatch(str, length) {
  for (var h = length; h < str.length; h++) {
    if (str[h] === ' ') { 
      strMatch = "";
      console.log('white Space')
    } else {
      strMatch += str[h];
      //
      if (strMatch === strToSearch) {

          var len2 = str.length - strMatch.length;
          console.log(len2,"Matched...");
          wordMatch(str, len2-1);
          strMatch = "";
          //return false;
      }else{
        console.log('cont.........................')

      }
    }

  }
}
wordMatch(str, 0);
```